# How to add alarm sound or ringtone to apk?

Tags: android, alarm, ringtone

Can I add alarm sound or ringtone to apk ?
I need to add to alarm sound to the application we developing.
Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand, do you want to trigger a sound when your application opened ?

Comment: I had the alarm application written. We wanted to add our own alarm tone or sound as part of the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Steps you need to do:

1. Add song that you want to add into res->raw folder.
2. Then in your activity write this:

`Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        AlarmIntent.putExtra("Ringtone", 
                Uri.parse("getResources().getResourceName(R.raw.shankh_final_mid)"));
        PendingIntent Sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, AlarmIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager AlmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        AlmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 
                (60 * 1000), (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), Sender);`

3. After that in your reciever class add this line of codes:

   ```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 

   Intent in = new Intent(context, SnoozeEvent.class);
   in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   PendingIntent Sender = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Wake up alarm", System.currentTimeMillis());
   notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Hanuman Chalisa", "Wake Up...", Sender);
   notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
   notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/raw/notification");
   manager.notify(1, notification); }
   ```

Comment: Hi Charlie
Thanks. We completed the alarm application.
Since the alarm application was completed and able to select different sound.
Just add our own alarm sound/sound to res->raw will do ?

Comment: Yes, and you need to point that alarm sound in your code as i do.